# Storm real-time processing: What if it goes down?

Tags: bigdata, apache-storm

Storm is a free and open source distributed realtime computation system. It receives streams of data and does processing on it. What if Storm goes down and part of the data never goes through it which means that calculations would not be in sync?

How can Storm solve this problem? If it can't, how could one solve this problem?

A similar question would be: How can I read old data that existed before Storm was added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I read old data that existed before Storm was added?

The data must be stored somewhere (say, HDFS). You write a Spout which accepts data from some transport (say, JMS). Then, you would need to write replay code to read the appropriate data from HDFS, put it on a JMS channel, and Storm would deal with it. The trick is knowing how far back you need to go in the data, which is probably the responsibility of an external system, like the replay code. This replay code may consult a database, or the results of Storm's processing, whatever they may be.

Overall, the 'what if it goes down' question depends on what type of calculations you are doing, and if your system deals with back pressure. In short, much of the durability of your streams are dependent on the messaging/transport mechanism that delivers to Storm.

Example: If you need to simply tranform (xslt) individual events, then there is no real-time failure, and no state issues if Storm goes down. You simply start back up and resume processing.

The system that provides your feed may need to handle the back pressure. Messaging transports like [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/%20Kafka) can handle durable messaging, and allow Storm to resume where it left off.

The specific use case that results in "calculations would not be in sync" would need to be expounded upon to provide a better, more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For example, let's say Twitters Storm goes down and misses 2 hours of clicks and tweets. It goes back online and resumes calculations but the metrics (tweets per day, etc.) are off by 2 hours. How does it solve this problem, do you know?

Comment: Assuming that Twitter is using a messaging system like Kafka, there is no problem with that. The messages "clicked" and "tweeted" just idle in the queue until Storm is back.